# Checkboxes not showing in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable and the checkboxes are not being displayed. Everything else I put inside the column will show but checkboxes wont and I'm going crazy. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#companylist').DataTable({
    dom: '<lf> <t><ip><"clear">',
    ajax: {
      url: 'data/companylist-ajax.php',
      dataSrc: '',
    },
    bPaginate: true,
    scrollX: "100%",
    order: [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    scrollCollapse: true,
    bAutoWidth: true,
    aLengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    "columns": [{
        data: null,
        render: function(datad) {
          //return '<input type="checkbox" name="selectcompanyid">';
          return '<label><input type="checkbox" name="test[]"></label>';
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "regoffice_city"
      },
      {
        "data": "regoffice_country"
      },
      {
        "data": "is_customer"
      },
      {
        "data": "is_supplier"
      },
      {
        data: null,
        render: function(data) {
          return '<a class="btn btn-default  btn-sm" href="viewcompany.php?companyid=' + data[0] + '"><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye fa-lg" style="color: gray"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="delcompanybtn" data-href="data/deletecompany.php?companyid=' + data[0] + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-id="' + data[0] + '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash   fa-lg"></i></a>';
        }

      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine in isolation. Any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors but just found the issue...
Forgot to include the datatable select js file

Comment: There should have been a very big red console error then :)